# disjoint union Topology question

Tags: general-topology

Is the usual topology on $[0,2)$ equal to the topology $\mathcal{T}_{\sqcup}$, obtained from the usual topologies on $X_1=[0,1)$ and $X_2=[1,2)$?

The answer given in the lecture was No, based on some arguments involving the inverse of the inclusion map.

However, I was quite confused and did not understand it..

Any help to explain this will be sincerely appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is [1,2) an open set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The topology on $[0,1) \cup [1,2)$ taken as a topological sum of $X_1$ and $X_2$ has the property that $U \subseteq [0,1) \cup [ 1 , 2 )$ is open iff $U \cap [0,1)$ is open in $X_1$ and $U \cap [1,2)$ is open in $X_2$.

Note that the set $U = [1,2)$ has the property that $U \cap [0,1) = \emptyset$ is open in $X_1$ and $U \cap [1,2) = [1,2)$ is open in $X_2$, and is therefore open in the topological sum.  However this set is clearly not open in the subspace $[0,2)$ of $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me fashion the argument in Arthur's answer slightly differently. First note that in the topological sum of $A$ and $B$, both $A$ and $B$ are clopen in $A\sqcup B$.

If the topologies were the same then the identity map would be continuous from $\cal T$ (the standard topology) to $\cal T_\sqcup$. The continuous image of a connected space is connected, but $([0,2],\cal T_\sqcup)$ is not a connected space.

**To sum up:** $([0,2],\cal T)$ is connected, but $([0,2],\cal T_\sqcup)$ is not. They cannot be equal.